# Interpreting the pre-processing information of a the ridge regression

Tags: machine-learning, r, machine-learning-model

I have a dataframe of 39,600 records and 13 columns (12 of which are the predictors. 3 of the 12 are factor variables, the rest are numeric). The response variable `Class` has 2 outcomes ('Normal' and 'Malicious').

I tuned a ridge logistic regression as follows

```
library(glmnet) 
library(caret)

lambdas <- 10^seq(-3,3,length=100)

ridge_log_mod <- train(Class ~., 
                        data = df, 
                        method = "glmnet", 
                        preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                        trControl = trainControl("repeatedcv",
                                               number=10,
                                               repeats=3),
                        tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha=0, 
                                               lambda=lambdas)
)
```

However, when I examined the `ridge_log_mod`, it showed there were 13 variables (instead of 12) for the `Pre-processing` step as shown below

```
> ridge_log_mod
glmnet 

39600 samples
   12 predictor
    2 classes: 'Normal', 'Malicious' 

Pre-processing: centered (13), scaled (13)
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 35640, 35640, 35640, 35640, 35640, 35640, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  lambda        Accuracy   Kappa    
  1.000000e-03  0.9890320  0.9780640
  1.149757e-03  0.9890320  0.9780640
  1.321941e-03  0.9890320  0.9780640
  1.519911e-03  0.9890320  0.9780640
...
```

I simply couldn't understand where that number 13 came from. Did it mean the `train(.)` function also scaled the response variable `Class`? How did the function `train(.)` scale the 3 categorical variables? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Could this be the intercept of the model?